# Recover Synaptics Raid 6 after Mainboard Fail

Tags: raid, nas, synology-diskstation

I have a Synology DS415+ NAS with four drives setup as RAID 6. The device is rather old and the soldered-on CPU has had some problems before (specifics don't matter to this question), so I don't know how long the mainboard will continue to work. The device is rather old now, so getting a new mainboard might be difficult, especially if the NAS survives another few years.

I've read somewhere, that it might be complicated to transfer a RAID system to another system due to RAID controllers working differently.

Is there any Synology-specific way to continue once the mainboard fails? Do Synology NASes use the same/compatible RAID controllers?

Comment: I cant comment on Synology specific ways  but Im fairly certain it is using Linux Software RAID (ie mdadm) under the hood. If this correct the data us recoverable using any pc with enough "standard" (hba/passthrough) interfaces using a common linux install like Ubuntu (although this does require a bit of expertise). That is to say there is no RAID controller to worry about  but its not using FakeRAID or Intel RST either.

Comment: Nice, thanks! That calms me a bit.